# Android: ListView Load more (OnScrollListener) Search Filter

Tags: android, listview, search, load, adapter

I added load-more feature to my app and now I'm wondering, how can I accomplish, that my Search Filter will search also through the items, which are not yet loaded.

Do you have any advice, what is the best way to do it?

Thanks for any answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that depends how you have thought of search functionality.  For e.g if you want to make it a local filter then obviously it will filter only loaded items. If search is global then it can always reset current shown list with the filtered items.

In case of global search you can give some visual element to the user where he can switch back to core list.